# Changing Z-index Problems

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an old-RPG game on HTML, and I want to make a Function on Javascript
that makes the div of the player get lower than the obstacle, and when the top get higher than the obstacle, the z-index of the player go higher than the obstacle:

```
var top = parseInt($("#player").css("top"));
var hei = $("#player").height();
var total = top + hei;
var obTop = parseInt($("#obstacle").css("top"));
var obHei = $("#obstacle").height();
var obTotal = obHei + obTop;
if (total < obTotal) {
    player.style.zIndex = 1;
    $("#obstacle").css('z-index', 2);
} else {
    player.style.zIndex = 2;
    $("#obstacle").css('z-index', 1);
}
```

#### When top's player is higher than the obstacle (Fire)

[image: When top's player is higher than the obstacle (Fire)]

---

#### When top is Lower

[image: When top is Lower]

Comment: Are you using the DOM to store your entire game state, e.g. player position..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the Y positions of the objects in question. In this case, When the fire y is lower then the player y, You want to have the player have a higher Z-index than the fire. And Vice Versa, Where when the fire y is higher than the player y, you want the fire to have a higher Z-index than the fire. You could do something like this like this:

```
//Define player y and fire y 
player.style.zIndex = 1;
$("obstacle").css("z-index", 1);
if (playery > firey){
    player.style.zIndex = 2;
} else {
    $("obstacle").css("z-index", 2);
}
```

This hasnt been tested as there Is not a runnable example given.